# I'm need to know how put an interface of a method inside When() mockito method

Tags: java, android, mockito

I'm trying to simulate a method with mockito in Android Studio, but, one of the methods in the presenter class need an interface as parameter, but, when i call the method inside When() of Mockito this not recognize the interface. See the below code:

This is my MVP code example.

**SignUpContract** interface:

```
public interface SignUpContract {

interface view{
    void showSignInScreen();
    void onError(int code, String message);
}

interface model{

    interface onFinish<R>{
        void onResponse(R data);
        void onError(String error);
    }

    void trySignIn(onFinish onFinish, String name, String password);
}

interface presenter{
    void handleSignInButtonClick(String username, String password);
}
}
```

**SignUpModel:**

```
public class SignUpModel implements SignUpContract.model {

SignUpRepository repository;

public SignUpModel(){}

@Override
public void trySignIn(onFinish onFinish, String name, String password){
    repository = new SignUpRepository();
    String result = repository.signInUser(name, password);
    if(!result.isEmpty()){
        onFinish.onResponse(result);
    } else {
        onFinish.onError("Has error ocurred during the operation");
    }

}
}
```

**SignUpRepository:**

```
public class SignUpRepository {

public String signInUser(String username, String password){
    String data = "Someone";
    return data;
}

}
```

**SignUpPresenter:**

```
public class SignUpPresenter implements SignUpContract.presenter, 
SignUpContract.model.onFinish {

SignUpContract.view view;
SignUpContract.model model;

public SignUpPresenter(SignUpContract.view view, SignUpContract.model model){
    this.view = view;
    this.model = model;
}

@Override
public void handleSignInButtonClick(String username, String password) {
    try{
        model.trySignIn(this, username, password);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("",e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void onResponse(Object data) {
    view.showSignInScreen();
}

@Override
public void onError(String error) {
    view.onError(1, error);
}
}
```

this is my test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SignUpPresenterTest {

public static final String USERNAME = "username";
public static final String PASSWORD = "password";

@Mock SignUpContract.model model;
@Mock SignUpContract.model.onFinish listener;
@Mock SignUpContract.view view;

@InjectMocks SignUpPresenter SUT;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    SUT = new SignUpPresenter(view, model);
}

public void success() throws Exception {

    **when(model.trySignIn(any(SignUpContract.model.onFinish.class), any(String.class), any(String.class))).then(SUT.onResponse(1));**

}

@Test
public void try_signin_success() throws Exception{

    success();

    ArgumentCaptor<String> ac = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

    SUT.handleSignInButtonClick(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    verify(model, times(1)).trySignIn(any(SignUpContract.model.onFinish.class), ac.capture(), ac.capture());

    List<String> captures = ac.getAllValues();
    Assert.assertThat(captures.get(0), is(USERNAME));
    Assert.assertThat(captures.get(1), is(PASSWORD));

    verify(view).showSignInScreen();

}

}
```

Comment: hi @second the error is when i trying to use this 
 >> when(model.trySignIn(any(SignUpContract.model.onFinish.class), any(String.class), any(String.class))).then(SUT.onResponse(1)); >>

Comment: What kind of error you are actually getting: a compilation error or an exception when executing? If so add the necessary details to the question.

Comment: @second the method is marked with a red line and show: "when(T) in Mockito cannot be applied to (void)."

reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that void conforms to T.

Comment: In that case you are using the wrong syntax. You have to use one of the `do` methods first, for example: `doAnswer(...).when(model).trySignIn(any(SignUpContract.model.onFinish.class), any(String.class), any(String.class))`. For a more detailed example check this [`tutorial`](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-void-methods).

Comment: i tried with this:           

`doAnswer(new Answer() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                SignUpContract.model.onFinish callback = (SignUpContract.model.onFinish) args[1];
                callback.onResponse(1);
                return null;
            }
        }).when(model).trySignIn(listener, USERNAME, PASSWORD);`

but, doest'n work

Comment: Please edit all your comments into your question instead (comments eventually get wiped and having it in the question makes things more readable). What do you want to express with `it doesn't work`?

Comment: when i run the test, i'm getting the following error: `Wanted but not invoked:
view.showSignInScreen();
-> at com.example.androidunittesttdd.signup.presenter.SignUpPresenterTest.try_signin_success(SignUpPresenterTest.java:82)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206885/discussion-between-milleraios-and-second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code into an example to verify this myself.
I made a few changes, some are just for my convenience.
Note that I used JUnit5 with a newer mockito version (`3.2.4`) to test it.

1. You do not need to use both `@InjectMocks` and `@Before`, either one of them suffices.
2. You are using the wrong argument inside the `doAnswer`. It should have been `args[0]`.
3. Using `trySignIn(listener, USERNAME, PASSWORD);` did not work for me, because `listener` refers to a different mock while you are actually passed the class under test (`SUT`) along as parameter.
   I changed it to use matchers instead.

---

Edit:
I removed `SignUpModel` and `SignUpRespository` from my example as all the test does is to mock the interface. The implementation is not really relevant for your question.

### The `listener` mock is also not required as its not used anymore.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SignUpPresenterTest {

    public interface SignUpContract {

        interface view {
            void showSignInScreen();
            void onError(int code, String message);
        }

        interface model {

            interface onFinish<R> {
                void onResponse(R data);
                void onError(String error);
            }

            void trySignIn(onFinish onFinish, String name, String password);
        }

        interface presenter {
            void handleSignInButtonClick(String username, String password);
        }
    }

    public static class SignUpPresenter implements SignUpContract.presenter, SignUpContract.model.onFinish {

        SignUpContract.view view;
        SignUpContract.model model;

        public SignUpPresenter(SignUpContract.view view, SignUpContract.model model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleSignInButtonClick(String username, String password) {
            try {
                model.trySignIn(this, username, password);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Object data) {
            view.showSignInScreen();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
            view.onError(1, error);
        }
    }

    private static final String USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    @Mock
    SignUpContract.model model;

    @Mock
    SignUpContract.view view;

    SignUpPresenter SUT;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        SUT = new SignUpPresenter(view, model);
    }

    @Test
    public void try_signin_success() throws Exception {

        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                SignUpContract.model.onFinish callback = (SignUpContract.model.onFinish) args[0];
                callback.onResponse(0);
                return null;
            }
        }).when(model).trySignIn(Mockito.any(SignUpContract.model.onFinish.class), Mockito.eq(USERNAME), Mockito.eq(PASSWORD));

        ArgumentCaptor<String> ac = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

        SUT.handleSignInButtonClick(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        Mockito.verify(model, Mockito.times(1)).trySignIn(Mockito.any(SignUpContract.model.onFinish.class), ac.capture(), ac.capture());

        List<String> captures = ac.getAllValues();

        Assert.assertEquals(USERNAME, captures.get(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(PASSWORD, captures.get(1));

        Mockito.verify(view).showSignInScreen();
    }
}
```

---

Note that the verifcation of the `trySignIn` call is not really necessary, as your test does not work if the behaviour definition on the mock is not invoked. So this is already verified by the flow of the test.

Also try to follow the Java Naming Conventions: Class Names / Interface names  should start with an uppercase letter. That usually makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Part of the confusion yesterday came from that the `listener` is actually not used anymore. Anyway it didn't match to `SUT` thats why the defined behaviour did not match. I updated the answer to reflect this point.